# Using pointer to vector properly

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a pointer to vector setup in my IDE but i dont think im doing it right cuz everytime i try to push_back data into it the program crashed at that point in the code.  
For example:

```
std::vector<int> a;  std::vector<std::vector<int> > *a1;
a.push_back(3);
a1->push_back(a); // Right here the program crashes with no indication prior to execution that there was an error.
```

I've seen some other users of this site have pointers of vectors initialized but now that i think about it i dont recall them really accessing them to put data in or to edit later. Maybe thats why im stuck at this point getting Crashes. So could anyone explain why it and happens how to do pointer to vectors properly. I want to access vector a1 like so:

```
cout<<" value is: "<<(*a1)[0][0] + 4 <<endl; // I cant even reach this far when the program runs
```

What about this im not getting right?

Comment: You didn't initialize `a1` to anything. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: afaict just access it (with no dereference) is UB by itself.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson Could u further explain plz with a quick example or something that would be highly appreciated

Comment: A pointer needs to point at something to be useful. You can point it at `nullptr` so that people know explicitly that its not pointed at a valid object. You can point it at a dynamic allocation (something you almost never want to do with a `vector` because `vector`'s job is to perform the nitty-gritty details of memory management for you). You can point it at a pre-existing object. You have to point it at something or you don't know what will happen when you try to use it. Probably it will crash, but the real nightmare is when the pointer happens to point at valid memory and "stomps" it.

Comment: Note that the compiler [can warn you if you ask it politely](https://godbolt.org/z/Ez4xf6K5s), but if the code is syntactically correct it is not required to issue any warnings even if the logic is completely wrong.

Comment: Please note that there's almost never a reason to have a pointer to a standard container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is a vector. Below is a declaration (and definition) of `a`:

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

`a1` is a pointer to a vector. Below is a declaration and definition of `a1`, but *the pointer doesn't point at a defined location* (thanks to @user4581301, for pointing that out):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > *a1;
```

In order to define the value in `a1`, one could either assign the address of an already existing vector or allocate a new vector via `new`, e.g.

```
//pre defined vector
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;

//assign address of a to a1
std::vector<std::vector<int>> *a1 = &a;

//or allocate a new vector
std::vector<std::vector<int>> *a2 = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

The intent of the above code was to show how an address of an object **could** be obtained, either via the address of `&` or the `new` operator.

When it comes to 'best practice', i would say, avoid pointers use references. But when an allocation is needed, then

- one could wrap the pointer either into an `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` object (guaranteed deallocation of the allocated memory block, e.g. in case of an uncaught exception)

e.g.

```
//allocate a single vector<int> and insert the values 1, 2, 3
auto my_vec_ptr = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(1, 2, 3);
//(*my_vec_ptr).push_back(42); //dereference pointer and add the value 42

//allocates an array of 5 vector<int>
auto my_vec_array = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>[]>(5);
//my_vec_array[0].push_back(42); //adds 42 to the first vector
```

- or use a container, like vector, map, etc.

e.g.

```
//constructs the vector with 5 default-inserted instances of vector<int>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec_of_vec{5};
//my_vec_of_vec[0].push_back(42); //adds 42 to the first vector
//my_vec_of_vec.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}); //add a new vector to the list
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> *a2 = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>;` -- If a C++ programmer sees that, that is a red flag that something isn't quite right.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please elaborate more what that might be? If i did wrong, help me out to do it right.

Comment: why would you dynamically allocate a container whose main purpose it to keep the manual managment of dynamically allocated elements away from the user? And even if you do, you should not use a raw pointer for that

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Instead of using `new` one should use `std::make_unique` or similar to get the benefits of RAII. See [C++ Core Guideline R.1](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r1-manage-resources-automatically-using-resource-handles-and-raii-resource-acquisition-is-initialization). I would go even further and say that nesting vectors is a red flag in most cases, because people often misuse this for allocating a regular matrix which should be continuous in memory.

Comment: @GoreDistrict This is not specific to `std::vector` at all. Pointers are a basic part of the C++ language which one should know **before** getting into any tutorials about library features like `std::vector`. Learning the basics will save you a lot of time in the long term, so please start at the beginning.

Comment: @GoreDistrict Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is not a support forum. There are better places to get the kind of support that you are searching for.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number _"One could do that"_, never said _"do that"_. When it comes to 'best practice', yes you're right. There are multiple (encouraged and discouraged) ways to allocate, manage and retrieve the address of an object, but that was not the issue here.

Comment: @paleonix But i do know this pointer stuff. Not that much tho with vectors i use pointers all the time but i never knew even with vectors u should go: std::vector<std::vector<int>> *a1 = &a; . What im use to is something like: int k; int * y= &k;

Comment: @paleonix see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75549236/using-pointer-to-vector-properly/75549382#comment133292841_75549382

Comment: using a pointer does not imply dynamic allocations, dynamic allocations do not imply pointers. Your answer puts something that is bad practice on the same level as something that is completely fine. Imho there is no need to mention `new` here at all.

Comment: @GoreDistrict Again, it has nothing to do with vectors. It is part of the language and works the exact same way for any type or class.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number _"using a pointer does not imply dynamic allocations, ..."_ and where in my answer do i make that statement? What meaning has the word **could** for you?

Comment: you bring dynamic allocation to the table when thats not the topic, but the topic is a raw poitner. That can easily give the impression that it would be sensible to make a raw pointer point to a vector allocated via `new`.

Comment: @paleonix U mention earlier "this is not a support forums & that they're better places i can go to get the kind support i'm searching for. " So can u give me some names so i can check them in the future. I would appreciate all the help i can get when code issues are getting a bit too stubborn.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number _"could either or"_, why are you so stuborn and insisting? The OP got his answer and is satisfied, what is your problem? Is my code wrong, is it not standard conform, ... no? End of story. You gave your statement, that it is discouraged to use `new` (and i agreed), i think we all got it. Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: I am not stubborn. I made a point, you ask for clarification, I try to clarify. If you do not want to see the point then just leave it be

Comment: there is this tendency of taking critisim of contents personally. To defend the answer at all costs. I am commenting in the hope to help to improve the answer. If you don't think it can be imprvoed ok, no need to fight, no need to convince me of anything

Comment: @GoreDistrict I think that many communities are using Discord nowadays. If you search the internet for "C++ discord" you will find a lot of results that might be better for short term help. StackOverflow is great for looking up your problem, but the general consensus is that asking a good question here is harder than answering one. The focus is on future readers of any Q&A, not on the person who initially asks it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number _"When it comes to 'best practice', yes you're right."_ We should have left it there.

Comment: @GoreDistrict "What im use to is something like: int k; int * y= &k;" but thats exactly the same with the vector. really not much different.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük -- The first two examples, I can see in C++ code.  For example, if there are two or more `std::vector<std::vector>>` in play, and you want to point to only one for further processing, the second example makes some sense.  The last example using `new` looks like a Java or C# programmer's attempt in writing C++ code without learning C++ properly.  That's the first impression it would give if a C++ programmer were to see that line of code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Hahaha lol Yeah now i know. But in all my life in C++ & watching videos on Youtube I've never ever seen a vector go like that. Like its another pointer simple int, float, char etc.. pointer. Seriously i could not believe it when i saw it here being shown to me as the Solution haha. That was crazy to know u can use vector like that as well

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, i understand what you mean. My goal was not to show how it should be done, but more how a pointer variable **could** be populated by a value (address). I admit, my fault was to use that, what came first into my mind when i thought of an heap allocation address (first example stack allocation, and i thought it would be a good idea to give another - different - example, but obviously not).

Comment: @Erdal Küçük either way i dont care its all extra information for me & i appreciate it. i already know not to use  `new` unless i want to go dynamic memory. So I'm all good here really haha

Comment: @GoreDistrict The point is to use containers/RAII wrappers **even if you want a dynamic allocation**. Library developers might need to use `new` to implement their own containers/RAII wrappers, but normal application developers are better off without it for C++14 and later (there was no `make_unique` factory function in C++11, so `new` for initializing a smart pointer was ok).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number A voice inside my head told me, that one does not call someone 'stuburn' even if they're 'insistently' trying to make their point. So be it, i will take the word stuborn back and if an apology is due, my sincere apologies.

Comment: cool. Sometimes trying to get a point across can sound harsh and as non-native speaker, choosing not the best words is just natural, and most of the times its both sides. Btw I see you edited your answer. Just fyi, I still think bringing dynamic allocations to the table is suboptimal, but I wouldnt fight for it, and its not worth a downvote.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Got it, as i previously said to PaulMcKenzie, allocation came into my mind when i thought of 'addresses'. In a more general sense, it could be mentioned, but specific to the OP's question, it is as you said suboptimal. I hope the additional information makes it clear, that the allocation part should/could be considered as an 'excursion'.